# Get entries count

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-api

I'd like to make a **JSON** - **request** to Google using multiple keywords like for example:

- Query: '`this is a test`'

... And what I'd like to get a result is the **result-count of Google entries** that have been found.

---

[image: image: Google result screenshot]

- Result: `2.810.000.000`

I made a JSON request to the [google-custom search api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) using this setup:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?
q=test&
cx=008053715732182427479:b-zr4bw_m2i&
key=myKey
```

(I've added just `google.com` as **search-machine website** in the **Google custom search** menu. `cx` is the ID of [my public google search machine](https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=008053715732182427479:b-zr4bw_m2i) that)

[image: img]

Result: `2.800.000.000`

... Is not the same as in my custom search:

[image: img2]

Result: `130.000.000`

... And also not the same number as the one from the JSON-request:

[image: img]

How to get the result `2.800.000.000` as an answer to the JSON request?

Comment: Google personalizes search results when using the site, have you considered that?

Comment: Please share the response that you got the initial number from with us. Otherwise we can't tell how you got that number